# Push Notification for web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, push-notification

I have been tasked to add push notification for a web site being developed. Never done one before. I spent a long time googling this and I am not much closer than when I started searching, mostly because most articles describe specific details.

The web application is an intranet app and they are asking for things like when a new report is made available, let the users know about it; or basically any kind of organization/department announcements.

Can someone tell me what are the components involved in developing/deploying this type push notifications? If I know what the pieces are that make this process possible, I can take it from there. I must mention that this web application is being designed to be available on devices (desktop, tablets and phones; if this makes any difference in design/development).

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ He's talking about push notifications, not UI notifications.

Comment: Yup, I didn't read properly

Comment: Ok, In this case you can use SignalR. Refer http://www.codemag.com/Article/1210071

Answer (score 0):

You can try [OneSignal Push Notification](https://onesignal.com/)

in this you can send notifications to websites,android app and ios app

You can also check the documentation for sending notifications to website [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-http)

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I can't use third party services.

Comment: without using thirdparty services you cannot do pushnotification easily, it takes lot of time and effort

Comment: Thank you. I will check this. Can you tell me what are the components in a push notification? What pieces need to be in place in order for push notification to work?

Comment: You need to configure it in your web application and then need to push from services